# How can I show recently answered questions and answers in my blog site?

Tags: support, api, questions, answers, widget

I would like to showcase some of my Stack Exchange answers in my blog site. I couldn't find a relevant post on how to implement this.

Also, from what I can see, in order to use the API a user needs to login into his account. I cant go with that concept, since there may be lot of visitors who do not have a Stack Exchange account but I want to show them my recently answered questions anyway.

Is that possible with the Stack Exchange API? If possible give me some hints on how to implement it.

Comment: See [here](http://stackapps.com/q/518/), [here](http://stackapps.com/q/3237/), [here](http://stackapps.com/q/2370/), etc.

Comment: @BrockAdams : Thanks for your comment. However I want to show questions which I most recently answered. I just need 4 questions. Using stackTack we can show only a particular question and it's answer, I guess. Unfortunately that is not what I need. I want to show most recently answered threads  and those questions should be get automatically updated !

Comment: If you look at each of those posts, they all link to their code.  You can use that as a start for your own app.